# Object detection training: will mirroring images help or hinder?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Will Tensorflow training benefit from doubling the images by mirroring images (flipping horizontally)?

In other words, if the original image contains text that says: "this is a test", the mirrored image would be "tset a si sith".

My instinct says Tensorflow's selection of object detection algorhthyms  will not benefit. What's the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Flipping images horizontally is a common data augmentation technique for many computer vision tasks including object detection, and is very likely implemented in tensorflow. It'll probably help performance.

Of course there are cases where it makes less sense: for example, if you are trying to detect relevant road signs, which always appear on the right hand side of a lane...

Comment: "which always appear on the right hand side of a lane"... I would question the "always"  [Exhibit 1](https://res.cloudinary.com/carsguide/image/upload/f_auto,fl_lossy,q_auto,t_cg_hero_large/v1/editorial/australian-animal-warning.jpg) . . . [Exhibit 2](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-hPDlGnd9h1k/S_2AAvXjnlI/AAAAAAAAFDs/pkn1VvE6G2IidtOUsU6G0x4xsnroyE1YgCHMYBhgL/s800/Highway%2BSign%2B-%2BCantilever%2BVariable%2BMessage%2BSign%2B%2528VMS%2529.JPG). Case 1 may be an issue if you're trying to sell a system internationally; a system only trained on one side of the road may be dangerous...

Comment: Does anyone know whether shimao is correct that tensorflow probably does flip images horizontally?